# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'PaddingFIFOQueue' with these attrs

Tags: c++, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to run Tensorflow model using C++ API and getting this error:

```
Running model failed: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'PaddingFIFOQueue' with these attrs
 [[Node: batch/padding_fifo_queue = PaddingFIFOQueue[capacity=32, component_types=[DT_FLOAT], container="", shapes=[[-1,-1,3]], shared_name=""]()]]
```

Only information I was able to find is that the issue might be due to GPU only operation. But I have intentionally tried to run model in CPU only mode using original Python code and it works fine.

Clearly don't know what should I check now.

model+graph: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5yk3/No887jqS8

Comment: That error also happens when the .pb file was produced by a newer version of TensorFlow

Comment: btw, .pbtxt is easier to debug than `.pb` file (produced by `print(tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def())`, someone could reproduce your problem by copy-pasting just the `PaddingFIFOQueue` part into own file, and loading that with `tf.import_graph_def`